# SPARQL Query to find common neighbours for several entities

Tags: sparql

One example: I want to find the dbo:spouse for dbr:Barack Obama, dbr:Ronald Reagan, and dbr:Donald Trump, in one query, under the same variable.

Comment: What do you mean more precisely?
If the neighbours are common then your example is wrong, as Obama, Reagan and Trump have never been married to the same person.

If instead you mean to ask how to return the spouse of each, then it is very easy, and I'll provide an answer below.

Comment: I am trying to find the spouse of each.

Comment: I think it's possible to edit the question title to improve it. @ValerioCocchi is right that the word "common" in the question is misleading so perhaps you could rephrase it to SPARQL Query to find neighbours for several _specific_ entities? This helps other people later on find the question when they want to know the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VALUES function, like this.

```
SELECT ?president ?spouse
WHERE{
    ?president dbo:spouse ?spouse .
    VALUES ?president {dbr:Barack_Obama dbr:Ronald_Reagan dbr:Donald_Trump}
}
```

Also, IRIs are not allowed to have unescaped spaces and even then the rules are somewhat complicated, so I usually use an underscore to represent them.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I am looking for :)